# DefHTMLHeaderByName doesn't seem to work mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to get a document generated on a php site. It is all working well but the last thing is to add a header to the top of every page after the title page. I have tried so many things and the closest I can get to what I want is the following (stripped down) code.

```
  ob_start();

  $mpdf = new Mpdf();

  $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
  $mpdf->bleedMargin = 0;
  $mdpf->crossMarkMargin = 0;
  $mpdf->cropMarkMargin = 0;
  $mpdf->nonPrintMargin = 0;
  // Home page and headers...
  $html_header = 'Some Code here';
  $mpdf->DefHTMLHeaderByName('PgHeader', $html_header);

  $mpdf->AddPage();
  $mpdf->Image('cover.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, 'jpg', '', true, false);


    // Get the content of any pages we have 
    if($pdf_pages) {
      foreach($pdf_pages as $key=>$pg) {
        $mpdf->AddPageByArray(array(
          'mgt' => '40',
          'odd-header-name' => 'PgHeader'
        ));
        $html .= 'the content from the loop';

          // Write some HTML code:
          $custom_sheet = file_get_contents('/custom.css');

          $mpdf->WriteHTML($custom_sheet, 1);
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
      }
    }

  // Output a PDF file directly to the browser
  $mpdf->Output('Name.pdf', 'I');

  ob_end_flush();
```

I have tried changing the odd-header-name to html_PgHeader based on the documentation but in either case, I get the margin, all the content but the header never shows up. Why? Why is it not being assigned so I can call it in the AddPageByArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show header, you need to add `odd-header-value` option to `AddPageByArray` method with value `1`.

```
  ob_start();

  $mpdf = new Mpdf();

  $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
  $mpdf->bleedMargin = 0;
  $mdpf->crossMarkMargin = 0;
  $mpdf->cropMarkMargin = 0;
  $mpdf->nonPrintMargin = 0;
  // Home page and headers...
  $html_header = 'Some Code here';
  $mpdf->DefHTMLHeaderByName('PgHeader', $html_header);

  $mpdf->AddPage();
  $mpdf->Image('cover.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, 'jpg', '', true, false);

  $pdf_pages = array('key' => 'val');

    // Get the content of any pages we have 
    if($pdf_pages) {
      foreach($pdf_pages as $key=>$pg) {
        $mpdf->AddPageByArray(array(
          'mgt' => '40',
          'odd-header-name' => 'PgHeader',
          'odd-header-value' => 1,
        ));
        $html .= 'the content from the loop';

          // Write some HTML code:
          $custom_sheet = file_get_contents('/custom.css');

          $mpdf->WriteHTML($custom_sheet, 1);
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
      }
    }

  // Output a PDF file directly to the browser
  $mpdf->Output('Name.pdf', 'I');

  ob_end_flush();
```

**Pt.II**

If this, don't help, then try this scenario:

1. Open console and go to site's root path.
2. Create index.php file
3. Run `composer require mpdf/mpdf` (install composer, if you don't have it).
4. Paste this code to the index.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

ob_start();
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();


/** same code from previous example here, except Mpdf init **/
```

Comment: Tried adding that and it still doesn't work. Same result

Comment: Did you set $pdf_pages array? If not, add `$pdf_pages = array('key' => 'val');` (you can copy updated answer) and scroll to second page. If you set `$pdf_pages` and still doesn't work on second page, then try version from updated answer `Part 2`.

Comment: I have massively stripped down the code I am putting in here as it is looping through some WP stuff and isn't really relevant to what I am trying to acheive. Needless to say, the foreach loop returns the content and that part is working fine. (I have about 10 pages in the test I am using and they have a margin of 40 at the top of the pages). Couldn't see what was different about the second part - probably just missing it though

Comment: Second part using composer. Maybe your version of `mpdf` handle options of creating page with bug.

Comment: ok. So I currently am using mpdf as a standalone folder that I have downloaded. It's version 6.1 is that a problem?

Comment: I'm using 7.1 version. Get it from GitHub and try to run.

Comment: Example #4 from https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-4.html should work in any case, but i suppose, that you need to set header only via object?

Comment: Zen - the problem with that was adding in the margins to the top of the pages didn't seem to work which is why I am creating the Pages manually rather than just adding in HTML. I can't share any more code than I have. Honestly the other stuff isn't relevant as it is pretty much just putting a string of html for each page.

Comment: I think, you can solve problem by this steps: 1. Use/create new virtual site on local server and  try to run example from my answer with last `mpdf v7.1`. It should definitely work (tested on php 7.1).

Comment: 2. If this example don't work for you, then you have some fundamental problems with php (incompatible php version/don't have any of extension/settings in php.ini). If works fine, then copy this code to WP and make it generate page, like in a raw example.

Comment: 3. Modify raw example at WP to what you need and test it at stages, that code still generate header on pages.

Comment: So in the end it was a version issue. I still have a couple of problems but this seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you need to prefix header/footer names with '**html_**'

Try changing;

```
'odd-header-name' => 'PgHeader',
```

to;

```
'odd-header-name' => 'html_PgHeader',
```

reference [here](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpagebyarray.html)

Comment: Thanks for including a reference to the documentation!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You will note I had tried that in the original answer. The issue was using an older version

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
@page {
 header: header_name;
 footer: footer_name;
}
```

It might help you.

Url: https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html

Comment: Unfortunately not working either. It feels to me more like the header isn't getting set by the DefHTMLHeaderByName method rather than it not being picked up by the pages but I could be wrong.

Comment: you are including header and footer in html format?? or a static text?

Comment: No footer just header and it is a string of html (a div with an image inside it) - $html_header = '<div style="position: absolute; left:0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;"><img src="document-header.jpg"style="width: 210mm; margin: 0;" /></div>';

Comment: What is your mpdf version? if you are getting any errors please post it here

Comment: That's the annoying thing. No errors coming out. Using v 6.1 but going to try 7.1 just now